# Passing custom properties inside SVG use instance

Tags: css, svg

After reading this article outlining how to assign colors to svg elements inside of a use instance I wanted to see if I could use the pattern to apply to other properties like animation etc. Basically trying to animate different instances of the same icon in separate ways.

**Article**
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/lets-make-your-svg-symbol-icons-multi-colored-with-css-variables-cddd1769fca4

**Pen I created to test**
https://codepen.io/asleepy/pen/PQWJVj

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="defs-only">
<symbol viewBox="0 0 15 15" id="icon-radio">
    <circle id="circle-outer" cx="7.5" cy="7.5" r="6.5" 
                    fill="var(--outer-fill-color)" 
                    stroke="var(--outer-stroke-color)" />
    <circle id="circle-inner" cx="7.5" cy="7.5" r="4.5" 
                    fill="var(--inner-fill-color)" 
                    stroke="var(--inner-stroke-color)" />
</symbol>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 15 15" class="icon-radio one">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-radio" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 15 15" class="icon-radio two">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-radio" />
</svg>
<style>
[class^='icon-'] {
    width: 3rem;
    transition-duration: 0.195s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 1, 1);
    transition-property: var(--inner-fill-color);
    will-change: var(--inner-fill-color);
    &:hover {
        --inner-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
}

#circle-outer {
    stroke-width: 2;
}

.one {
    --outer-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    --outer-stroke-color: rgba(210, 120, 150, 0.8);
    --inner-fill-color: rgba(123, 12, 34, 1);
    --inner-stroke-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.two {
    --outer-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    --outer-stroke-color: rgba(23, 47, 26, 1);
    --inner-fill-color: rgba(4, 23, 69, 1);
    --inner-stroke-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
</style>
```

The animation doesn't work though. It just jumps to the end state as if the transition is invalid.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the transition on the use element, but transitions are not inheritable. Define it instead on the fill property of the referenced circle.

```css
.icon-radio {
    width: 3rem;
}
.icon-radio:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#circle-outer {
    stroke-width: 2;
}

#circle-inner {
    transition-duration: 0.195s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 1, 1);
    transition-property: fill;
    will-change: fill;
}

.one {
    --outer-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    --outer-stroke-color: rgba(210, 120, 150, 0.8);
    --inner-fill-color: rgba(123, 12, 34, 1);
    --inner-stroke-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.one:hover {
    --inner-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.two {
    --outer-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    --outer-stroke-color: rgba(23, 47, 26, 1);
    --inner-fill-color: rgba(4, 23, 69, 1);
    --inner-stroke-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.two:hover { /* to demonstrate different colors still can be used */
    --inner-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 128, 1);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="defs-only">
<symbol viewBox="0 0 15 15" id="icon-radio">
    <circle id="circle-outer" cx="7.5" cy="7.5" r="6.5" 
                    fill="var(--outer-fill-color)" 
                    stroke="var(--outer-stroke-color)" />
    <circle id="circle-inner" cx="7.5" cy="7.5" r="4.5" 
                    fill="var(--inner-fill-color)" 
                    stroke="var(--inner-stroke-color)" />
</symbol>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 15 15" class="icon-radio one">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-radio" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 15 15" class="icon-radio two">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-radio" />
</svg>
```

Comment: your logic sounds right. i can't make it work in my codepen though. it's still behaving the same :/ were you able to make it work?

Comment: You need to target the use element: `.one:hover { --inner-fill-color: rgba(123, 123, 123, 0.32); }`. `.one #circle` is not a valid selector.

Comment: Currently, your symbol element has an `id="icon-radio"` and the use elements have a `class="icon-radio"`. Do yourself a favour and give them different names, so you won't confuse the two.